# Why is my text so small in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, font-size

[image]

I’ve tried adjusting my font to bigger sizes but it still looks small. It’s currently set at 72 and it is still tiny. Any reason why it’s not its normal size?

Comment: 25% zoom could certainly make any text look small.

Comment: @usr2564301: That should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: Get your rulers on: `Command` + `R`

Answer (score 2):

Your text, at an inch high, is not small. It only appears as such, because your *document* is large – shockingly so. I estimate it to be around 55.6x35 inch (141x89 cm), which seems total overkill.

Presumably you did not check your ruler units when entering your desired size.